# Kivy How to create widgets from dictionary in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, dry

I am new to the library kivy for Python. I found the additional library kivy-md which has very good looking ui elements. At the moment I want to create many MDTextField widgets from a dictionary variable e.g.

```
# text_fields.py
text_fields = {
    "text_field1": {
        "key": 0,
        "self": "text_field1",
        "hint_text": "Textfield 1",
        "helper_text": "This is textfield 1",
    },

    "text_field2": {
        "key": 1,
        "self": "text_field2",
        "hint_text": "Textfield 2",
        "helper_text": "This is textfield 2",
    }
}
```

From this variable, I want to create widgets in the kv file that look like

```
GridLayout:
    MDTextField:
        id: text_field1
        hint_text: text_fields["text_field1"]["hint_text"]
        helper_text: text_fields["text_field1"]["helper_text"]
        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        on_text_validate: app.on_text_validate(text_fields["text_field1"]["self"])
    MDTextField:
        id: text_field2
        hint_text: text_fields["text_field2"]["hint_text"]
        helper_text: text_fields["text_field2"]["helper_text"]
        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        on_text_validate: app.on_text_validate(text_fields["text_field2"]["self"])
```

I see two challenges in this problem that I am not able to solve. The first is how to parse the id values from the dictionary strings and the second problem is that I do not know how to loop over kivy widgets in a kv file.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: @eyllanesc: I don't know how to generate it in the code either. But I would prefer it to be inside the kv file such that layout and logic are separated.

Comment: Hmm ... I don't really understand your comment. At the moment all my code inside my main.py simply does something, but it does not generate the layout and what is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note there are no attributes, `self` and `key` in KivyMD MDTextField. In the example, we use nested `for` loop to access the dictionary, `text_fields.py`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.textfields import MDTextField
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from text_fields import text_fields
from functools import partial


class RootWidget(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        app = App.get_running_app()
        for key, fields in text_fields.items():
            mdt = MDTextField(id=key, helper_text_mode="on_focus")
            for subfield, value in fields.items():
                mdt.subfield = str(value)
            mdt.bind(on_text_validate=partial(app.on_text_validate, text_fields[key]["self"]))
            self.add_widget(mdt)


class MainApp(App):
    title = "KivyMD MDTextField Demo"
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

    def on_text_validate(self, value, obj):
        print("\napp.on_text_validate:")
        print("\tobj=", obj)
        print("\tvalue=", value)
        print("\tobj.text=", obj.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but as it seems the upvotes are not accepted for new users. I will need some time to transfer this solution on my problem. If I am successful I will accept the answer.

Comment: It is difficult for me to adopt this procedure to my problem because my layout is much more complicated. But I will accept this answer because it seems to work for the example that I have given. Thank you for your patience.